# I'm getting the error 'EntityType has no key defined' even though I've defined a key in both the model and the database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

[I've been following this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/working-with-multiple-tables-in-mvc-using-entity-framework/) on  how to handle multiple tables in MVC and I came across an error when trying to make a view for Index (Step 12 in the tutorial) specifying 'EntityType has no key defined'. The only solution I was able to find was to put a [Key] attribute before the primary key member in the model class. However when I tried to make a View again the same error came up.

**The Controller code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RelationalDatabaseWebsite.Models;

namespace RelationalDatabaseWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class UsersTablesController : Controller
    {
        private ApprenticeTestEntities db = new ApprenticeTestEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            UsersLogContext cs = new UsersLogContext();
            List<Log> logs = cs.Log.ToList(); 
            return View(logs);
        }
```

**Code for the Log model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;



namespace RelationalDatabaseWebsite.Models
{
    [Table("LogTable")]
    public class Log
    {
        [Key]
        public int LogTableID { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string TimeLogged { get; set; }

        public virtual UsersTable Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Users Model code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace RelationalDatabaseWebsite.Models
{
    [Table("UsersTable")]
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Salt { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AddressTable> Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DOBTable> DOB { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LogTable> Log { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**DbContext Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace RelationalDatabaseWebsite.Models
{
    public class UsersLogContext : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Log> Log { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Users Database Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersTable](
    [UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Salt] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsAdmin] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Log Database Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogTable](
    [LogTableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TimeLogged] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogTable_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LogTableID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LogTable_UsersTable] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UsersTable] ([UserID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LogTable_UsersTable]
GO
```

Apologies for the mass of code it's just that given the error was raised with both the Log and the Users table I would put both pieces down in case the respective errors are related to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Users` table has a key type of **uniqueidentifier** but your code model has a key type of **int**

```
[Key]
public int UserID { get; set; }
```

...

```
[UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
```

Try changing the key in your user model (and its related property in the Log model) to be of type `Guid`...

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid UserID { get; set; }
```

Comment: And because the uniqueidentifier column is also your key column, the DB will have to generate the UserID. You will need to tell this to EF: e.g.  __[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]__

Comment: Thanks @DanielSchmid, I've edited the answer to include your correction.